# Vue: display alert only when a value is not falsy or 0 from api?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, computed-properties

I'm having some issues trying to find a solution for a situation where I only want to display an info bar if the value is not falsy or 0. I'm retrieving some data from an api and storing it in state when the page loads but there's a brief moment where the value is empty while the request is happening and the info bar is displayed. The state gets updated with the value and then the info bar disappears. I'm trying to avoid this behavior

```
<info-bar v-if="isThisValueFalsy&&Object.keys(getAlert).length>0"></info-bar>

computed: {
  ...mapState(['apiResponseObject']),

  isThisValueFalsy() {
   return this.apiResponseObject.value || this.apiResponseObject.value === 0;
 },

  getAlert() {
   if(!this.isThisValueFalsy) {
    const someObject = someOtherApiHelper;
    return someObject();
  }
 }
}
```

When I run console logs for apiResponseObject.value, I get 2 values: one where it's blank in the beginning and then another when the value gets updated. But my code briefly treats the initial blank as falsy and shows the info bar for a bit and then disappears when the api response is back and the state is updated. How can I show only if a truthy or 0 value comes back? Thanks

Comment: ` return this.apiResponseObject.value` - this is the check for truthy value

Comment: @EstusFlask yes but the issue is for a brief period of time the value is blank so it treats it as falsy and displays the info bar for a few seconds until the api response comes back and the state is updated.

Answer (score 0):

It just means that `apiResponseObject` is initialized with an empty string. So transform it into a falsy value.

Also in your example, you are referencing `isValueFalsy` which doesn't seem to exist.